# How do I annotate a Mosaic Plot in R ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code I have is as follows:

```
mtcars_tab <- mtcars %>% count(cyl, gear) # counts the number of gear / cylinder combinations
mtcars_tab %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(gear), fill = cyl, weight = n), divider = mosaic("v")) +
    xlab("Gear") + 
    ylab("cyl") + 
  ggtitle("Distribution of Gears and Cylinders in the mtcars data")
```

I would like to annotate the n here on the rectangles of the mosaic plot (preferably centered).

[image: current plot]

Comment: Hi, you will find the answer to your question in this tutorial https://xang1234.github.io/mosaicdiagrams/

Comment: Please include all the non-base packages that you are using in the question.